# React useRef hook: Cannot access a single item in ref array by index

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my parent component, I initialize my ref with the useRef hook as an array, define a function to fill the array with items from a child component and then pass the function to the child component:

```
export function Game() {
  const dropZones = useRef([]);
  function pushRef(ref) {
    dropZones.current.push(ref);
  }
  return items.slice().sort((a, b) => a.idx - b.idx).map((item, idx) => (
            <DropZone 
                key={idx} 
                item={item} 
                pushRef={pushRef}/>))
```

In the child component, I call the function in an effect hook:

```
export function DropZone({item, pushRef}) {

const [dropZoneRef, setDropZoneRef] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(()=>{
    if(!loading) return;
    if(dropZoneRef && loading) {
        pushRef(dropZoneRef);
        setLoading(false);
    }
},[pushRef, dropZoneRef, loading]);

return (<div className="drop p-1 pt-2 text-center" ref={setDropZoneRef}>)
```

When I log dropZones.current, I get the expected result – an array of elements:

```
(5) [div.drop.p-1.pt-2.text-center, div.drop.p-1.pt-2.text-center, div.drop.p-1.pt-2.text-center, div.drop.p-1.pt-2.text-center, div.drop.p-1.pt-2.text-center]
```

But when I try to get a single item of the array, I get undefined:

```
dropZones.current[0] // undefined
```

How can I access a single item of the array?

Comment: something is wrong with your log code, maybe just a typo, can you share the 2 log lines please? and are they in the same place?

Comment: I copied the code from my console and pasted it here. I am sure that I copied everything that was logged to the console. But I cannot repeat it because I changed my code in the meantime from controlled refs to uncontrolled refs.

Comment: well, does it work now?

Comment: No, but I am sure now that the issue is caused by pushing the items before they were loaded. Still trying to fix that issue.

Comment: Is `DropZone` always in the DOM? because useRef is undefined until is actually added in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You should try storing dropZones.current in a separate variable and then index that variable. Something like follows:

```
const allElements = dropZones.current;
const myElement = allElements[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the meantime, I got a result without storing the elements in another variable. It seems to be caused by the fact that the elements were pushed before they were loaded. Weird, that logging dropZones.current showed five elements, though.

Comment: Good to hear that you fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

With uncontrolled refs, I got it to work now. Still not sure what made the difference and why the array was populated with the correct items while I could not access them with their indexes. But changing the part where I push the items in my child component **DropZone** made the difference. I changed this:

```
const [dropZoneRef, setDropZoneRef] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(()=>{
    if(!loading) return;
    if(dropZoneRef && loading) {
        pushRef(dropZoneRef);
        setLoading(false);
    }
},[pushRef, dropZoneRef, loading]);
```

to this:

```
const dropZoneRef = useRef(null);
const loading = useRef(true);

useEffect(()=>{
    if(dropZoneRef.current && loading.current) {
        pushRef(dropZoneRef);
        loading.current = false;
    }
},[pushRef]);
```